# How to add the handler to five dynamic buttons

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have in my Page_Load event the following code:

```
    For number As Integer = 1 To 5
        Dim btn As Button = New Button With {
                .Text = "Test" & number.ToString(),
                .ID = "Test" & number.ToString()
                }

        AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf btn_Click

        buttons.Controls.Add(btn)
    Next
```

And the event handler right below the Page_Load:

```
Private Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    Debug.WriteLine($"Button {btn.Text} was pressed")

End Sub
```

I am not doing something right with the AddHandler because it doesn't fire when I click on any of the five buttons. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure the `AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf btn_Click` code is not inside an IsPostBack check.

Answer (score -1):

i have slightly edited your code as i am working in VB.NET but this works for me i had to change the position of each button according to the integer as VB.NET  lays each button in the top left corner of the form. let me know how you get on

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

```
    For number As Integer = 1 To 5

        Dim btn As Button = New Button With {
                                    .Text = "Test" & number.ToString(),
                                    .Name = "Test" & number.ToString(),
                                    .Top = number.ToString * 20
        }

        AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf btn_Click



        Me.Controls.Add(btn)
    Next



End Sub


Private Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    Debug.WriteLine($"Button {btn.Text} was pressed")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

End Class